# Callbacks & params.require -- Can someone explain these to me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I apologize if this is a silly but I have no idea what the following piece of code does

```
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_article
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :post, :user_id)
end
end
```

I'm new to rails and I have gotten a fairly good idea of MVC and how it all connects, but I just can't wrap my head around the code above found in the controller files. What's a callback and why would I use one? What is Article.find(params[:id]) doing? What does .permit do in this case? Does it mean that it'll only accept the title, post & user_id parameters and not anything else? And on top of all, why are both the methods private? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Callbacks** are methods that are called at some points of object's lifecycle. `set_article` is a callback, because it is called `before` particular controller actions(usually listed on top of the file). The reason for this is that you need to find an `article` from the database and assign it to an instance variable in all those actions. This method is meant to keep the code DRY(Do not Repeat Yourself), because if you don't have a private method for this, you would have to copy/paste the line inside the method for each controller action. That is fine as long as you don't need to change it EVER. That is why it is good practice to use callbacks for these kinds of methods.
- As mentioned before `@article = Article.find(params[:id])` finds an article in the database with a particular ID and assigns it to an instance variable, so you can later render it in a view (using, say, `@article.name` etc).
- **What does article_params method do?** It takes ALL the params that are passed to the request. then in checks for the construction of the params. In this case `params.require(:article).permit(:title, :post, :user_id)` it is waiting for params that look like `article: { title: "smth", param2: "val2" }` etc. That is what `.require(:article)` does. What `permit` does, is drop all other `params` except the ones you have whitelisted.

An example:

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :post, :user_id)
end
```

And let's say a hacker is trying to change forbidden attributes and sends a request like this `article: { title: "smth", post: "Hacked", user_id: 1, admin_id: 1(hackers user_id) }`

If you do `Article.find(params[:id]).update_attributes(params[:article])` it would try to write to the database ALLL the params that have been passed.

If you have the `article_params` method and you use that instead of raw params:  `Article.find(params[:id]).update_attributes(article_params)`

It will automatically DROP all non-whitelisted params, meaning that `article_params` will only contain `article: { title: "smth", post: "Hacked", user_id: 1}`

I hope This is clear now.

- **Private methods** In general private methods are methods that you cannot call outside the object itself. For example if `Article` has a private method `write` You cannot do:

  `article = Article.new
  article.write`

But if You use the same method when defining some public method for Article

```
class Article
 def needs_write
  #Do other stuff
  write
 end

 private

 def write
  puts "private" 
 end
end
```

Then calling `article.needs_write` would work, and would also call the `write` method.

It is a bit tricky to understand at first... + to make you more confused - you can, actually, call a private method directly on object via `send` method, but you shouldn't worry about that at first

Answer (score 0):

1. these actions are private because we dont want to access these actions outside the class.
2. def set_article
     @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   end
   this action runs before show and edit you can see at top before_action
   it is same as

   def show
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   end
   we use same thing in edit and show. so we dont want to repeat same thing agian and again. so we put it in an action.

   3. def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :post, :user_id)
      end
      this action is accept strong parameters. only these parameter will allow to store in databse